# Is there anyway to build a dependency graph for an Azure Subscription

Tags: azure

I need to walk the resources in an Azure Subscription and determine the dependencies of those resources, i.e. this LogicApp connects to or is triggered by that Service Bus topic, or, that API connects to this SQL Server etc.

I realise I could use the dependsOn attribute in the ARM template, but that may not be a true representation of *all* the resources in the subscription being parsed.

Does anyone know of a tool that can build a dependency graph?, or, Does anyone know if Azure Powershell provides enough information that can help me build a dependency graph of my own?

Comment: Application insights had the application map which might give you what you need, worth a look.

Comment: Would that give me a full dependency graph if for example a resource doesn't  have Application insights turned on?

Comment: Not 100% tbh but I know we see SQL Server, Storage, etc. in the map and we haven't turned on app insights for those resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing built into Azure itself, but there are a few options that may help depending on your requirements.

There is an open source ARM visualizer at http://armviz.io/designer.  You can import an ARM template and then it will create the diagram of your resources.  There is a walkthrough available at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureedu/2016/03/09/how-can-i-map-my-existing-azure-arm-resources-visually/.

There is another more fully featured resource visualizer that covers multiple cloud platforms at https://www.cloudockit.com/, but it is not free to use.

There are some other similar visualization tools that you might be interested in for helping visualize and manage your applications and infrastructure rather than just your Azure resources.

- Application Map in Application Insights - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-app-map.  It provides a more application centric architecture view rather than an infrastructure view and provides additional runtime insights such as performance and errors.
- Service Map in Operations Management Suite - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-walkthrough-servicemap.  This provides a more machine oriented infrastructure view showing the different connections and dependencies that a VM has.

You can also use Azure Resource Graph for this, but there isn't a list or built-in way to automatically detect all of the dependencies so you would have to build out this logic yourself.  There is a starter sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli#list-virtual-machines-with-their-network-interface-and-public-ip.

Answer (score 0):

@kwill answer helped me discovery that there is a "Visualize template" button ( it may be in preview) in Azure > Resource Groups > [group] > Automation:Export Template. I was able to use the visualize template button on a group that generated an ARM template of 180,086 lines; though it took many minutes to accomplish. I did not find any Microsoft documentation about this feature specifically; however, I did find the [Use Azure portal to export a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal). That Azure documentation guides you to the same area(s) where you can find the visualize template button. Also that documentation contains the following image which shows a greyed-out "View Template" (as of 2024-02-22 10:42 am PST):
[image]

I found that http://armviz.io site is still live, but kwill's specific link returned a 404 error. Armviz.io also links to [shenglol's GitHub arm-visualizer](https://github.com/shenglol/arm-visualizer) project (most recent commit is February 20, 2024).